# Hotmail Folders

Tags: gnome, kde, opensuse

Is there a linux mail client I can use that will let me see my folders in Hotmail and persist the changes back to the server? Kind of like the Hotmail connector for Outlook, or Windows Live Mail?

I'm using openSuse and KDE desktop, with Gnome application support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird and http://webmail.mozdev.org/setup.html.

see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/132232/can-i-synchronize-hotmail-folders-in-thunderbird) for the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't *any* IMAP client do that?

**Edit:** Whoops, I'm sorry, it looks like Hotmail doesn't support that (at least for any client except their own Outlook). Maybe trying to protect their investments?

According to this site, however, you can get the features of IMAP on your iPhone or iPod. [Email tutorial: Hotmail](http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/windowsLiveHotmail/configureHotmailSettingsOptions/hotmailImapSettings.php) At least that's something.

Comment: This was my thought too, but it might help if you include *how* to connect to Hotmail over IMAP